# Accessing UIApplication.sharedApplication() from a framework

Tags: ios, swift

I use a framework to share common code between my main application and a Today Extension. I frequently run into scenarios where I am attempting to access `UIApplication.sharedApplication()` (the main application singleton) that is running from my framework, to show alerts, open URLs, show image pickers, show spin selectors, etc.

As a temporary solution I have a global variable in the framework that I set to the UIApplication when the application starts, then the framework relies on that variable. This method feels wrong to me and I would love to know of a better solution.

What is the best practice for accessing the UIApplication singleton from my framework?

Answer (score 3):

Most likely you are missing the following import statement:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can build your framework, when it uses `UIApplication.sharedApplication()`, it is good solution as far as I can see than saving `UIApplication.sharedApplication()` in some variable.